# Suppress Confirmation Popup during msi installation

Tags: powershell

I am trying to uninstall the older version of the software and install the latest version. I have an uninstall script and an install script that does this. When I run the script as Powershell as Admin, the script executes successfully, but in non Admin mode, it prompts for a popup asking for confirmation,

Since I am trying to automate via pipeline I need to skip or suppress this popup,

```
msiexec.exe /i "installer.msi" /q
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name = 'installer'" | Remove-WmiObject
```

I have tried using /q, /quiet that did not help

Is there any way to suppress such prompt so that it can continue silently?

Comment: You can't bypass asking for confirmation for non-admin users. Installers that need to do so should run under an admin account.

Comment: @KenWhite, do we have any option to automate this confirmation via pipeline, I also see that when powershell is launched in Admin mode it doesnot ask for confirmation, but how do we launch powershell in admin mode via pipeline, when manually starting the powershell in admin mode it prompts for confirmation,